# Proving a quotient group $G/N$ is Isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

For $G=$$\mathbb{Z}$$\oplus$$\mathbb{Z}$ and $N=${$(x, y)$ | $3x=5y$}, prove that $G/N$$\cong$$\mathbb{Z}$.

I know that $G/N=${$aN$ | $a$$\in$$G$}, being $G\pmod N$.

As far as I can tell, this would be something along the lines of {$0(x, y), 1(x, y), 2(x, y)$...}

Thats as far as I got, its honestly the notation from $N$ that's confusing me the  most, because to me, $(x, y)$ for $3x=5y$ would be {$(5, 3), (10, 6), (15, 9)$....}

any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Try to find a map $G\to\mathbb Z$ such that $N$ is precisely its kernel. Then you can apply the first isomorphism theorem! For instance $(x,y)\mapsto 3x - 5y$ seems like a good start...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $N$ can be written as
$$N= \{ (x,y) : 3x-5y = 0 \}$$
hence it is the kernel of the group homomorphism $f: \Bbb{Z} \oplus \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}$
$$f(x,y) = 3x-5y$$

Now, it is sufficient to show that $f$ is onto (or equivalently, that $1$ is in the range of $f$): this is clear since $3$ and $5$ are coprime integers.

Hence by the isomorphism theorem
$$G/N  = G/ \ker f \cong f(G) = \Bbb{Z}$$

Comment: Actually I think its sufficient that $f$ is non-zero. (Since every subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.)

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes it much clearer!

Answer (score 1):

This easily follows from the first isomorphism theorem. First,  observes that $N=\{x(5,3): x\in \Bbb{Z}\}=(5,3)\Bbb{Z}$. Second, observe that $G/N\cong G/Z\}$ since the map $aN=a(5,3)\Bbb{Z}\mapsto a\Bbb{Z}$ is an isormophism. So the composition gives the desired result since $\phi:G\rightarrow Z$ given by $\phi(x,y)=3x-5y$ is a homomorphism with kernel $N$ .